# Java Spring (Maven) REST API using OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-restcontroller

Please help me with details given at article [Secure Spring REST API using OAuth2](http://websystique.com/spring-security/secure-spring-rest-api-using-oauth2/).

How to run the SpringRestClient from the given [source code](http://websystique.com/?smd_process_download=1&download_id=2926)?

Here's the pom.xml, what is missing?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.websystique.springmvc</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringSecurityOAuth2Example</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>SpringSecurityOAuth2Example</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
    <springsecurity.version>4.1.1.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
    <springsecurityoauth2.version>2.0.10.RELEASE</springsecurityoauth2.version>
    <jackson.library>2.7.5</jackson.library>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurity.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security OAuth2-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>${springsecurityoauth2.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson libraries -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.library}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>SpringSecurityOAuth2Example</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        <finalName>SpringSecurityOAuth2Example</finalName>
</build>
```

Please note that the Postman Client works fine. What is the Maven command to run the SpringRestClient Class? The SpringSecurityOAuth2Example.war is generated from mvn package.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your `pom.xml` is inside SpringSecurityOAuth2Example folder so from that folder you can run below command. Please make sure your war file is deployed in tomcat and server is running as SpringRestClient will look for service at http://localhost:8080/SpringSecurityOAuth2Example. Please restart you tomcat before running this command otherwise it might throw error.

```
mvn -Dexec.mainClass=com.websystique.springmvc.SpringRestClient -Dexec.classpathScope=test test-compile exec:java
```